# When will a function or method stop execution?

Tags: objective-c, function, methods, try-catch

What does this function return in Objective-C?

```
- (NSInteger)test1 {
    @try {
        return 1;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return 2;
    } @finally {
        return 3;
    }
    return 4;
}
```

**And when will a function or method stop execution?(not only the Objective-C code)**

------------ updated --------------

The result is 3.

What if I comment or remove the *return code* in *finally*, what will the function output?

```
- (NSInteger)test2 {
    @try {
        return 1;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return 2;
    } @finally {
        //return 3;
    }
    return 4;
}
```

the result is 1.

**I ask this question is to know when will the function stop execution.**

Comment: Yet you don't even tell us what language is it written in. (looks like Objective-C?)

Comment: Yeah, it's Objective-C. But the same result in java.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You can compile and run that code (with suitable boilerplate) and see for yourself.

Comment: @Avi Of course I know the answer. But my question is not the answer. It's the running principle of function or method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stops execution when it reaches the final line in the code path, so it's all a matter of understanding the code path.

General rules:

- code is executed in the order in which it appears.
- code in a finally block runs before the function returns to the caller.
- the value of the last return statement to be executed will be the return value of the function.

Now, let's apply those rules to your examples.

```
- (NSInteger)test1 {
    @try {
        return 1;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return 2;
    } @finally {
        return 3;
    }
    return 4;
}
```

The first statement to be executed is `return 1;`.  That it's in a `@try` block is actually irrelevant, as it doesn't throw an exception.  Because it's a return statement, the function is about to return.  However, there's a `@finally` block, so that executes next.  The only statement there is `return 3;`, so that executes and replaces the return value of the function, which had been set by the previous statement.

If you remove the code from the `@finally` block, or remove the block altogether, the code simply returns after executing the first statement, as it's a `return` statement.

`return` statements always short-circuit the execution of the function, and cause any cleanup code to be executed (e.g. `@finally` blocks in ObjC, `defer` blocks in Swift).

Comment: Thanks, you made it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.I called your coding in viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   NSInteger  i = [self test];
   NSLog(@"The value is - %ld",(long)i);
}


- (NSInteger)test {
@try 
{
    return 1;
  } @catch (NSException *exception) {
    return 2;
  } @finally {
    return 3;
  }
  return 4;
}
```

And it prints

```
The value is - 3
```

Actually first it calls the try block,then it calls the finally block.

> @try —Defines a block of code that is an exception handling domain:
> code that can potentially throw an exception.
>
> @catch() —Defines a block containing code for handling the exception
> thrown in the @try block. The parameter of @catch is the  exception
> object thrown locally; this is usually an NSException  object, but can
> be other types of objects, such as NSString objects.
>
> @finally — Defines a block of related code that is subsequently
> executed whether an exception is thrown or not.
> A finally block contains code that must be executed whether an exception is thrown or not.
>
> @throw — Throws an exception; this directive is almost identical in
> behavior to the raise method of NSException. You usually throw
> NSException objects, but are not limited to them. For more information
> about @throw, see Throwing Exceptions.

[Handling Exception](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the answer I wanted.

Comment: Then what else do you want exactly brother?

Comment: Brother if you do not call the finally it returns 1 brother

Comment: If you face any error in try block,then it calls the catch block brother.

Comment: But if you have finally block,no matter what happens it must or 100 percent calls the finally block brother.

Comment: Now do you understand brother?

Comment: Still if you don't understand,I will explain you very clearly

Comment: Thanks, but the above code is just an example. Truly I want to know is when will a function or method stop execution?(not only the Objective-C code) with the B sentence in the description. Maybe I did not say it clearly.

Comment: The above codes just make me to think of this question.